# Google Adword URL slowing site

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am noob so please ignore if this is a silly question. I have a client website.

http://jstillman.com

on GTmatrix Site loadtime is good. its under 4s. But seo team is using some url for adword so final URL looks like

https://www.jstillman.com/?keyword={keyword}

with this URL GTMATRIX shows like 8 to 14s load time i have no clue why is this happening.

If any of you can help it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your load time, might change for different URL as they use different images and content, maybe is a big image or another resource to be optimized.